How to renew a token in a SPA using spring-authorization-server
Have anybody successfully made a SPA with spring-authorization-server without cheating and customizing the PKCE flow in spring-authorization-server. All examples I have found, stops when the initial access token is issued. There is no description of what to do when after the token has expired.
How would you renew the token when spring-authorization-server does not issue refresh tokens for a public client?
The documentation recommends that you should use BFFs instead, but BFFs have a much larger attack surface because they introduce a middleman between the authorization server and the client.

According to the docs, this initial access token for client registration is issued from a client credentials grant, which does not support refresh tokens. When the existing token is expired, you can simply do another token call and get a new one.

"The documentation recommends that you should use SPAs instead" Do you mean BFF?

Yes of course, edited, thanks @SteveRiesenberg

@SuvinNimnakaSukka to get a token, you either use an authorization token or a refresh token. To get a new token without a refresh token, you need an authorization code, like the first time you called the token endpoiont. My question is then, how do you obtain one without refreshing the page? The very thing that refresh tokens should solve.

"BFFs have a much larger attack surface because they introduce a middleman between the authorization server and the client." What are you basing this statement on? This seems like a perception only.

Usually all the refresh tokens are stored centrally, that is a security risk because one hack exposes all of them, and they may not even be rotated. Even worse, not storing refresh tokens and only authenticate at login. If you have long lived sessions, then it is impossible to offboard using the idp. These are some of the issues that PKCE public client do not have.
